# Post of form append generated via jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I create fields via jquery, with a question and 2 answers, I need to collect these fields in post via php.

I generate them as follows:

```js
var length = wrapper.find(".fields").length;

$(wrapper).append('<div class="col-sm-12 fields fields'+ (length+1) +'">\

  <label >Pergunta</label>\
  <input type="text" value="" name="pergunta'+ (length+1) +'[]">\

  <label >resposta 1</label>\
  <input type="text" value="" name="resposta1'+ (length+1) +'[]">\

  <label >resposta 2</label>\
  <input type="text" value="" name="resposta2'+ (length+1) +'[]">\

  <input type="text"  value="" name="item[]">\
');
```

The problem in question is that in the foreach post I need to collect the answers to each question.

```php
$size = sizeof($_POST['item']);
for ($i = 0;$i < $size;$i++)
{
  echo 'pergunta:' .$_POST["pergunta1"].'<br>';
}
```

In this way I know there is no way to set the namedo input directly, because it is dynamic.

Comment: I suggest you add a hidden form field which gets the names of all dynamically added form fields as value. You could do this either seperated by some delimiter, or you could have an array of hidden inputs.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, pleas mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group them by an arbitrary index so you can get their values by index in the backend (I changed your formatting a bit):

```
var length = wrapper.find(".fields").length;

$(wrapper).append('<div class="col-sm-12 fields fields'+ (length+1) +'">'+

  '<label >Pergunta</label>'+
  '<input type="text" value="" name="pergunta['+ (length+1) +']">'+

  '<label >resposta 1</label>'+
  '<input type="text" value="" name="resposta1['+ (length+1) +']">'+

  '<label >resposta 2</label>'+
  '<input type="text" value="" name="resposta2['+ (length+1) +']">'+

  '<input type="text"  value="" name="item['+ (length+1) +']">'
);
```

Supposing `length=5`, this will output form inputs with names "pergunta[6]", "resposta1[6]", "resposta2[6]" and "intem[6]".

Then you get the values like so:

```
    // now pergunta, resposta, items etc will by indexed arrays:
    foreach($_POST['item'] as $key => $items)
    {
      echo 'pergunta:' .$_POST["pergunta"][$key].'<br>';
      echo 'resposta1:' .$_POST["resposta1"][$key].'<br>';
      echo 'resposta2:' .$_POST["resposta2"][$key].'<br>';
    }
```

It's not the cleanest way of doing this but I tried to follow your architecture.

Check [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94554) for more details on why I output multidimensional arrays with jQuery.

Obs.: I think that you are using "item" just as a control, so it should be a hidden input.